# Python вывод суммы

Tags: python

Привет. Есть одна проблема.Суть в том, что есть массив, на входе, который, заполняется целыми числами, чье количество 2016. Нужно вывести сумму и его слагаемые всех четных или нечетных чисел, зависимо от того, каким является максимальное в массиве. Программа должа вывести сумму слагаемых четных или нечетных чисел, например, 1+3+5=9.
Я сделал какой то китайский способ, он кривой и некрасивый, [посмотреть здесь](http://ideone.com/ek9TfU).

```
a = []
N = 2016
for i in range(0, N):
    a.append(i)
m = 0
for i in range(0, N):
    if (a[i] > m):
        m = a[i]
p = 0
if (m%2 == 0):
    for i in range(0, N):
        if (a[i]%2 == 0):
            print("+", a[i], end="")
            p = p + a[i]
else:
    for i in range(0, N):
        if (not a[i]%2 == 0):
            print("+", a[i], end="")
            p = p + a[i]
print("=", p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вывести сумму чётных чисел из списка, если максимум в списке является чётным числом и наоборот (вывести сумму нечётных чисел, если наибольшее число нечётно):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

numbers = [32, 90, 61, 28, 44, 52,  5, 44, 22, 48, 13]
max_is_odd = max(numbers) & 1  # whether the maximum is odd or even
chosen = [n for n in numbers if n & 1 == max_is_odd]  # evens or odds
print("{} = {}".format(" + ".join(map(str, chosen)), sum(chosen)))
```

#### Результат

```
32 + 90 + 28 + 44 + 52 + 44 + 22 + 48 = 360
```

Answer (score 2):

Монгольский способ:

```
numbers = set(range(2016))
odds = {x for x in numbers if x % 2}
evens = numbers - odds
odds_sum = sum(odds)
evens_sum = sum(evens)
print('{}={}'.format('+'.join(map(str, odds)), odds_sum))
print('{}={}'.format('+'.join(map(str, evens)), evens_sum))
```

Comment: 1- Код в вопросе выводит только одну сумму в зависимости от того является `max(numbers)` чётным или нет. 2- если  числа могут повторяться во входном массиве, то `set` не стоит использовать.